Cardano full node disk space needed
Was looking around and didn't find such answer for today. How much space do you need to run cardano full node?

Today full node require 184 GB of disk space.
Detailed output:
4.0K    db/gsm
5.1G    db/ledger
45M     db/volatile
178G    db/immutable
